# ubuntu 14.04 is not installing

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I downloaded image file of ubuntu 14.04(64-bit) from the website. I made a bootable dvd from that file and tried to install it. But the installation process was terminated and a window displayed a message that there is some problem with the cd/dvd or the hard disk. But when I booted ubuntu 12.04 from same kind of dvd on the same drive, it got installed properly. I am not able to understand what is the problem.
Can somebody help?

Comment: I would try performing the MD5 check as above, and re-downloading the image. FYI: I sometimes have issues reading from the CD, but that's because the BD-ROM drive itself is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with an MD5 Checksum on your image.
You should get the following number with `md5sum ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153. If not you should redownload the image.